# Copy one or more rows in grid janus and paste it

Tags: janus

I want to copy one or multiple rows in janus grid 3 and paste it into grid . my grid is bound

Answer (score 0):

what I know, gridex does not support copying rows to another grid.
what u have to do in this case is make a copy from the selected row/rows, and then add them directly to the databinding.

more info on what u want to do could be nice aswell

Answer (score 0):

Right, it doesn't support this.  I needed to paste row data into Exel, and was surprised that Janus didn't support this.

So I wrote a Copy routine to step through the selected rows, and build a string that has tabs between column entries and line-feeds after each row.  Load that to the Clipboard, and pasting to Excel worked fine.